# Unorganized XML response to VB.NET DataTable

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am getting the XML response from other application as shown in last here. It does not have a proper schema in response. I do not have any control on their response.

I am trying to convert this XML response into VB.Net DataTable.
Generally, One record shall contain 6 nodes (6 columns).

Issue is: Not all the records get all 6 nodes in XML Response. Some records have only 5 nodes.

i.e:  If you see below sample code, first and third records have all 6 values.
but second record has only 5 values, ( is missing in second record).

To identify when a new record begins i n RAW xml, I wrote the following code with loop for each node but then when a particular 6th node is missing, the loop number does not match, and values get posted in other records.

How can I resolve this?

Following is my VB.Net code.

```vb
Private Sub PullData(ByVal XMLData As String)

    Dim PullRequest As WebRequest
    Dim RequestXML As String = ""
    RequestXML = XMLData ' Called XML Function
    PullRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:9000")
    CType(PullRequest, HttpWebRequest).UserAgent = ".NET Framework Example Client"
    PullRequest.Method = "POST"
    Dim postData As String = RequestXML
    Dim byteArray() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
    PullRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    PullRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
    Try
        Dim dataStream As Stream = PullRequest.GetRequestStream
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
        dataStream.Close()
        Dim response1 As WebResponse = PullRequest.GetResponse
        Dim Response As String = CType(response1, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription.ToString
        dataStream = response1.GetResponseStream
        Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(dataStream)
        Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd.ToString

        If responseFromServer <> "" And responseFromServer.ToString().Length > 23

            Dim xmlDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
            xmlDoc.LoadXml(responseFromServer)
            Dim xpath As String = "//ENVELOPE/DSPVCHDATE"
            Dim nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(xpath)

            Dim Dt As New DataTable
            Dt.Columns.Clear()
            If Dt.Rows.Count > 0
                Dt.Rows.Clear()
            End If
            Dt.Columns.Add("DSPVCHDATE")
            Dt.Columns.Add("DSPVCHLEDACCOUNT")
            Dt.Columns.Add("DSPVCHTYPE")
            Dt.Columns.Add("DSPVCHDRAMT")
            Dt.Columns.Add("DSPVCHCRAMT")
            Dt.Columns.Add("DSPEXPLVCHNUMBER")

            For Each childrenNode As XmlNode In nodes
                For I As Integer = 0 To nodes.Count
                  
                    Dim NewDR As DataRow = Dt.NewRow
                    NewDR("DSPVCHDATE") = childrenNode.SelectNodes("//DSPVCHDATE").Item(I).InnerText
                    NewDR("DSPVCHLEDACCOUNT") = childrenNode.SelectNodes("//DSPVCHLEDACCOUNT").Item(I).InnerText
                    NewDR("DSPVCHTYPE") = childrenNode.SelectNodes("//DSPVCHTYPE").Item(I).InnerText
                    If childrenNode.SelectNodes("//DSPVCHDRAMT").Item(I).InnerText = ""
                        NewDR("DSPVCHDRAMT") = 0
                    Else
                        NewDR("DSPVCHDRAMT") = childrenNode.SelectNodes("//DSPVCHDRAMT").Item(I).InnerText
                    End If
                    If childrenNode.SelectNodes("//DSPVCHCRAMT").Item(I).InnerText = ""
                        NewDR("DSPVCHCRAMT") = 0
                    Else
                        NewDR("DSPVCHCRAMT") = childrenNode.SelectNodes("//DSPVCHCRAMT").Item(I).InnerText
                    End If
                   
                         If childrenNode.SelectNodes("//DSPEXPLVCHNUMBER").Item(I).Value isnot Nothing
                            If childrenNode.SelectNodes("//DSPEXPLVCHNUMBER").Item(I).InnerText.ToString() = ""
                                NewDR("DSPEXPLVCHNUMBER") = ""
                            Else
                                NewDR("DSPEXPLVCHNUMBER") = childrenNode.SelectNodes("//DSPEXPLVCHNUMBER").Item(I).InnerText.Replace("No. :", "").Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "")
                            End If
                        Else
                            NewDR("DSPEXPLVCHNUMBER") = ""
                        End If
                    End If

                    Dt.Rows.Add(NewDR)

                    If nodes.count = Dt.Rows.Count
```

And following is my input XML

```xml
<ENVELOPE>
    <DSPVCHDATE>10-1-2020</DSPVCHDATE>
    <DSPVCHLEDACCOUNT>ABC LLC</DSPVCHLEDACCOUNT>
    <DSPVCHTYPE>Pymt</DSPVCHTYPE>
    <DSPVCHDRAMT></DSPVCHDRAMT>
    <DSPVCHCRAMT>263.00</DSPVCHCRAMT>
    <DSPEXPLVCHNUMBER>(No. :EV5235)</DSPEXPLVCHNUMBER>

    <DSPVCHDATE>10-1-2020</DSPVCHDATE>
    <DSPVCHLEDACCOUNT>Cash</DSPVCHLEDACCOUNT>
    <DSPVCHTYPE>Ctra</DSPVCHTYPE>
    <DSPVCHDRAMT>-2720.00</DSPVCHDRAMT>
    <DSPVCHCRAMT></DSPVCHCRAMT>

    <DSPVCHDATE>11-1-2020</DSPVCHDATE>
    <DSPVCHLEDACCOUNT>XYZ LLC</DSPVCHLEDACCOUNT>
    <DSPVCHTYPE>Rcpt</DSPVCHTYPE>
    <DSPVCHDRAMT>-230.00</DSPVCHDRAMT>
    <DSPVCHCRAMT></DSPVCHCRAMT>
    <DSPEXPLVCHNUMBER>(No. :RC6289)</DSPEXPLVCHNUMBER>
</ENVELOPE>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try linq

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)
        Dim envelope As XElement = doc.Descendants("ENVELOPE").FirstOrDefault()
        Dim dates As DateTime() = envelope.Descendants("DSPVCHDATE").Select(Function(x) CType(x, DateTime)).ToArray()
        Dim account As String() = envelope.Descendants("DSPVCHLEDACCOUNT").Select(Function(x) CType(x, String)).ToArray()
        Dim chType As String() = envelope.Descendants("DSPVCHTYPE").Select(Function(x) CType(x, String)).ToArray()
        Dim drAmt = envelope.Descendants("DSPVCHDRAMT").Select(Function(x) If(CType(x, String).Length = 0, vbNull, CType(x, Decimal))).ToArray()
        Dim crAmt = envelope.Descendants("DSPVCHCRAMT").Select(Function(x) If(CType(x, String).Length = 0, vbNull, CType(x, Decimal))).ToArray()
        Dim number As String() = envelope.Descendants("DSPEXPLVCHNUMBER").Select(Function(x) CType(x, String)).ToArray()


    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Still same issue, with given my sample XML and your code, it returns 3 values in "dates","account","chType" but in "number" it returns only 2 values, so when we insert into table it will insert these 2 values in first 2 rows out of total 3. Actually 3rd "number" value in xml  should go into 3rd record only, and 2nd record should have null/blank value in number field of datatable

Comment: In my sample XML data, if you see in the middle, that record does not have an element  "number", while the other two records have it.

Comment: My code has two IF statements to handle the nulls.  I'm putting vbNull and you can replace vbNull with a value like zero.

Comment: I tried to change last line as follow,=====  Dim number As String() = envelope.Descendants("DSPEXPLVCHNUMBER").Select(Function(x) If(CType(x, String).Length = 0, "0", CType(x, String))).ToArray() 
.  ======   But this gives same result, "number" variable array returns only 2 values, and it does not fill 0

Comment: You do not need double quotes around the zero since it is a number.  Should be :  If(CType(x, String).Length = 0, 0, CType(x, Decimal))).ToArray()  I'm using string only to see if item is empty.  You really want a number returned.

Comment: I have to take double quote "0" because i have set  "Dim number As String() " and this variable might contain character hence it is string.

Comment: Dim number As String() = envelope.Descendants("DSPEXPLVCHNUMBER").Select(Function(x) If(CType(x, String).Length = 0, "0", CType(x, String))).ToArray()

Comment: When I developed the code 2 days ago  I had same issue.  That is why I remove "As ToString()"

Comment: but if we remove  "As ToString()" , then it does not work with varchar/string values

Comment: You are getting string instead of a number.  Look at my code I'm using CType(x, Decimal)) while you are using CType(x, String))

Comment: VB.net not allowing ==== Dim number As String() = envelope.Descendants("DSPEXPLVCHNUMBER").Select(Function(x)  If(CType(x, String).Length = 0, 0, CType(x, Decimal))).ToArray() ,  >>>  and if i do Dim number = envelope.Descendants("DSPEXPLVCHNUMBER").Select(Function(x)  If(CType(x, String).Length = 0, 0, CType(x, Decimal))).ToArray()   === It throws error " {"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type 'System.String[]'."} 
"

Comment: From :  CType(x, String).Length = 0 To : CType(x, object) = VB.Null   looks like you cannot convert a null to a string.

Comment: Not wrong, but it doesn't work in Net.  It looks like the error is due to casting the object  to a string. Not all object types have a ToString() method with a length property.